# Can we check the equality of two lines based on the slope and sum of the coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given the following example, I want to know if this ratiocination is correct.

If we have the coordinates of leading and trailing of some lines, how we can detect the equal lines without comparing the coordinates together.

In this case is it true to say two line are equal if the sum of all coordinates and the slopes are equal? I couldn't find any Counterexample.

e.g.:

```
a = [[2, 5], [6, 7]]
sum_of_points = 2 + 5 + 6 + 7
```

Comment: By "line" you mean a segment, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:

```
b = [[0, 7], [4, 9]]
```

It has the same slope and sum of coordinates as your "a" but is a different line segment.

In general, to specify a segment you need FOUR numbers, not just two.